# Nested While Loops not working

Tags: python, while-loop, match

I'm trying to use a while-loop to find a match between two values. One is static while the other is an entry in a list. This is the code:

```
 while count != 10:

    for x in rawinput[pos]:
       a = ord(x)
       hash = hash + a

    print hashlist[247]
    print hash
    print wordlist[247]

    while hash != hashlist[247]:
       pass


    print wordlist[247]
    hash = 0 
    count = count + 1
```

In reality, hash DOES equal hashlist[247], but instead of recognizing it and continuing the code with print wordlist[247], python gets hung up at the nested While loop. Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: Fixed Indentation and removed non-relevant variables.

Edit #2: All variables are defined earlier in the script. This is only a snippet of code that is giving me trouble. Hash and Hashlist[247] are equal (print hash and print hashlist[247] each give 848 as output).

Edit #3: SOLVED -- Thanks for the help!

Comment: The indentation of your code is all wrong, this possibly happened when posting the question. Could you edit your question, paste the original code instead of what is there now, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even realize that :/, reposting now.

Comment: What is the type of these values? What is in the hashlist exactly?

Comment: `hash` is a built in function in Python.  You might want to rename that variable.

Comment: `while hash != hashlist[247]:` is incorrect unless `hashlist` implement `__getitem__` and does something special there (or `__eq__`).

Comment: Hashlist is a list of numbers generated from another list. I'll try changing the hash variable name and see if that helps... I'm also not quite sure what you mean khachik, why isn't that correct? I've always specified positions within a list like that without any trouble in the past.

Comment: @user543790 I meant: if `hash` and `hashlist[247]` don't equal, `while hash != hashlist[247]:` will be infinite.

Comment: maybe try printing out `hash - hashlist[247]`. This might tell you if you have some sort of type problem.. and if they are equal then you should end up with zero. Or you could just check the types of those variables with `type()`.

Comment: @khachik Oh ok. Yea, I know that, I rewrote this version of the code to "debug" the program. Hashlist[247] and Hash are equal however (I confirmed this by hand, normally I'd have a variable there and a function under that while loop, but for readability I posted it like this). @Justin Peel I'll try that method and see if it works any better.

Comment: `while count != 10:`  count needs to be given a value before checking if it is  equal 10 ; if it is > 10  then count = count+1 will not help unless the number wraps around.

Comment: @Frayser -This is only a snippet of the code. Count is declared as count = 0 at the beggeining of the script. I'll mention that in the OP.

Comment: `print repr(hashlist[247]), repr(hash)` and you'll find one of them isn't the type you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to hash and hashlist being of a different type :/. str and int. I overlooked this, since the python interpreter didn't mention anything about a typeerror, which I'm used to it doing, and I simply forgot to check.

Thanks to everyone for your help!

To anyone who has a similar problem:

DOUBLE CHECK YOUR TYPES!!!

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted doesn't nest any while loops.

```
while count != 10:

    for x in rawinput[pos]:
       a = ord(x)
       hash = hash + a
```

This is the only relevant code. This is an infinite loop assuming count didn't start at 10.

Comment: There was a problem with indentation when I posted it... Thanks for your reply anyway. The second "while" loop is meant to be nested within the first.

Answer (score 3):

**Thing 1:** the Pythonic way of doing something 10 times is

```
for _ in range(10):
    ...
```

**Thing 2:** clearly Python thinks that `hash != hashlist[247]`, or it wouldn't loop infinitely. Try `print hash, hashlist[247], hash == hashlist[247]` to check.

**Thing 3:** what's the point of `while cond: pass` anyway? Are you trying to do multithreaded stuff or something?

Comment: 1: Thanks, Ill keep that in mind :) 2: Yes, they are all equal. Printing the two variables gives me "848" each time. 3: There would normally be a function there, but I posted it like this just to make it readable. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @user: so what do you get when you do `print hash == hashlist[247]`? True or False?

Comment: Interstingly, I get false. I'm guessing that means this is a type problem.

Comment: @user: well, you knew that you would get False, because otherwise the loop wouldn't have gone forever! But now at least you see where the problem is. You are correct that this is a type problem: do `print type(hash), type(hashlist[247])` to see it. Are you sure that one isn't `847` and the other `'847'`?

Comment: The interpreter prints 848 both times, no quotes or anything, but earlier on I used string.split to create hashlist, and forgot to convert the numbers to integers. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the updated post (with indented code): the top-level `while` will be infinite, if the initial value of `count` is greater than `10`.

Also, if `hash != hashlist[247]`, the following loop will be infinite as well (if there are no custom `__getitem__, __eq__` and changing values from another thread):

```
...
while hash != hashlist[247]:
   pass
...
```